# Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем выражены выделенные места + их синтаксическая функция

Tags: синтаксис

1) *Они намыливали его и выше и ниже пояса, осушали полотенцами из египетского хлопка и массировали ему тело, а он – **хоть бы что**.*

2) *Другой человек, **не Доменико Сориано**, непременно задался бы вопросом: …*

3) *Она была готова поступить так же **сколько угодно раз**.*

+Помогите определить тип выделенных предложений пожалуйста!

4) *Ей не оставалось ничего другого, **разве что послушаться его**.*

5) *Она захлебнулaсь от неожиданности – **как это вдруг он решился сделать ей предложение** - и сказала: …*

6) *Он ушел, не дожидаясь, **когда подадут кофе**.* (*когда* оно здесь не временное, да? надо спрашивать *не дожидаясь чего*? получается определительное?)

Огромное спасибо!

Comment: В (6) опущено слово "момента": "...ушёл, не дожидаясь *момента*, когда...", так что всё-таки временное, похоже.

Comment: Пример (4) немножко коряво написан.  Я бы сказал: "...ничего другого, **кроме как** послушаться его" или "кроме того чтобы послушаться его".

Comment: Victor, согласна c (4)! когда я анализировала и старалась парафразировать для меня, чтобы легче было понять, тоже пришла к этому наречию, но предложения так уже заданы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. а он – ***хоть бы что*** - фразеологизм в значение ***безразлично, равнодушно.*** Употреблен в функции предикатива.
2. ***не Доменико Сориано*** - уточняющее обособленное приложение.
3. ***сколько угодно раз*** -  нареч. качеств.-количеств. Употреблен в функции обстоятельства меры и степени.
4. ***разве что послушаться его.*** Предложение простое,присоединённым ограничительным частицой "разве что".
5. ***как это вдруг он решился сделать ей предложение*** - простое предложение в составе сложного.
6. ***когда подадут кофе*** - Придаточное времени. В определительных придаточных предложениях союзное слово "когда" можно заменить на союзное слово "который". Т.к.придаточные определительные прикрепляются к главному при помощи союзных слов  Здесь ***"когда"*** - союз.

Comment: ... спасибо большое, Серж!!! Я сегодня следующую порцию уже приготовила : )

Comment: Да. видел. Мы постараемся ответить.